# jquery show overlay div on page load

Tags: jquery, html, onload

I want to do something that I've seen many examples of onclick, but I want to load a div when a user goes to the page.  Even StackOverflow does this (onlcick) when you try to insert a hyperlink.

How can I make a div overlay when a page loads using jquery?

BTW, I've searched around a decent amount but can't find something simple that my jquery simple mind can figure out.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're talking about is called a "modal" dialog.

There are many modal dialog plugins for jQuery.  My favorite is "simplemodal".

It's available here: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/
The samples are great too!

From the simplemodal site:

> As a chained jQuery function, you can call the modal() function on a jQuery element and a modal dialog will be displayed using the contents of that element. For example:
>
> $("#element-id").modal();

Comment: As a total newbie to this sort of thing, I greatly appreciate well documented code that I can pick apart and see what breaks.  SimpleModal did that for me and I got it working!  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) Dialog widget. Or search for "jQuery lightbox". The general idea is to use an absolutely positioned `div` set to `display:none`, and change it to be `display:block` when required.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){ // this will run when the document.ready event fires
    $("#myDivOverlay").show(); // this will show a div whose id is myDivOverlay
});
```

That help?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $thing = $("<div class='newDiv'>");
      $("body").append($thing);
 });
```

Comment: Yeesh!  Not on my game this AM :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I combined these two tuts [How to create a stunning and smooth popup using jQuery](http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/)  and  [Modal box on page load with jquery fancy box and cookie plugin](http://point47.com/journal/2010/06/modal-box-on-page-load-with-jquery-fancy-box-and-cookie-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(window).load(function()
        {
        $('#loading').fadeOut(3000); //fadeout the #loading div after 2000 milliseconds
        });

    $('#loading').css('height','100%'); //Put 100% height to the div

});
</script>
```

[See full tutorial and download source code](http://voidtricks.com/div-on-page-load-jquery/).